# strncpy and strcat not working the way I think they would c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, g++, c-strings

I have an assignment to implement a string object ourselves, and am currently stuck when trying to concatenate two such strings.  I figured I would go this route:

- allocate big enough space to hold
- insert beginning of holding string into new space up to index using strncpy(this part works)
- cat on the string I am inserting
- cat on the remainder of the holding string

Implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   int index = 6;//insertion position

   char * temp = new char[21];
   char * mystr = new char[21 + 7 +1];
   char * insert = new char[7];

   temp = "Hello this is a test";
   insert = " world ";

   strncpy(mystr, temp, index); 
   strcat(mystr + 7, insert);     
   strcat(mystr, temp + index);
   mystr[21 + 6] = '\0'; 

   cout << "mystr: " << mystr << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

that code prints out gibberish after Hello when using visual studios, but works when using g++ (with warnings), why the discrepancy?

Comment: Note #1: What you call "discrepancy" is commonly called "undefined behavior" :-) When you see gibberish printed, it almost certainly means that your string is not properly terminated. Note #2: When your code compiles with warnings, don't run it until you fix all warnings.

Comment: Don't tag C++ code as C.

Comment: @NeilKirk ok, good to know. Ive looked around at other posts and people seemed to get blasted if they werent using string functionality and tagged as c++. people saying they should just tag as c instead of c++ if not using functionality of c++ so I just wanted to cover my rear

Comment: Maybe you should use C++ strings and not get blasted and plus less bugs :)

Comment: The `strncpy` does not work because it doesn't terminate the string, and `strcat` requires that its first argument be nul-terminated. Also, `temp = "...";` overwrites the address of the memory you allocated earlier, so that would be a memory leak. On the whole, you'll find C++ strings *much* easier to work with, and probably more intuitive.

Comment: @NeilKirk I wish, I am in a class where the assignment is to create a new string class, so the professor wants us to not use string functionality as that would defeat the purpose

Comment: If you put that clearly at the start of your question, you wouldn't get blasted. It is only because you won't believe the number of people doing things the hard way for no reason and producing buggy software for us all..

Comment: @NeilKirk I will keep that mind for next time then for sure. I'm always a little nervous to put that this is a homework question at the top of the question because I figured a lot of people would just ignore the question then

Comment: You don't have to say it's homework; just define/list the constraints. We cannot accurately answer without knowing them, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing native c concepts with c++. Not a good idea.

This is better:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  // not cstring

using namespace std;

int main(){
   int index = 6;//insertion position

   string temp = "Hello this is a test";
   string insert = "world ";
   string mystr = temp.substr(0, index) + insert + temp.substr(index);

   cout << "mystr: " << mystr << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks rich, I mentioned in the comments that this was for an assignment where i need to create my own string class and the profess want us to not use string functionality to make it

Comment: My apologies. You have my sympathy. What a horrible project :)

Comment: no worries, it has definitely been a rough week, but Im finally finishing it up. memory leaks for days